# Bluetooth LAN between smartphones? One-to-many phone connections?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, windows-phone-8, mobile

I've done a little research but haven't started writing any tests yet.

Looking for confirmation or details around whether or not multiple smartphones are capable of creating a network amongst themselves via Bluetooth.

- Can 6 iPhones connect to each other and communicate?
- If so, are Windows 8, Lollipop, iOS7 up to date the same way? I read that Android KitKat wasn't able to be host/client, but the new Lollipop is capable.

If Phone #1 decides to be server, can it have a one-to-many relationship with other phones and talk to them individually?

If that's not possible, can they be connected in series where each one is a server/client?

If none of these are possible, what are available options other than using the internet?

Thanks guys!

Comment: You may be interested in the `Multipeer Connectivity` iOS framework.

Comment: Are you looking for mixed communication (i.e. a mixed network of iOS / Android / Windows Phone 8 devices)?

Comment: @SandyChapman Yeah. Android -> iOS. Windows -> Android. etc.

Comment: I think that Larme is correct. You should likely investigate multipeer connectivity to Android. Looks like it might be a bit difficult to find a how-to on this. Alternatively, you can look at Apple's BTLE (Smart Bluetooth) framework called CoreBluetooth. Transmission rates are very slow, but at least there's documentation available for both Android and iOS. In this scenario, the iOS device could function as a server with multiple connections (i.e. BTLE central connecting to multiple peripherals).

Answer (score 2):

In a bluetooth network configured as a ***[piconet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piconet)***, one device can communicate with up to **7 other devices** simultaneously. Take a look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/332767/limit-to-the-number-of-devices-that-can-be-paired-with-a-bluetooth-device) for a brief explanation.

On the theoretical side your are fine ;)